# Corresponding space to a irreducible part of a given representation of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory, group-actions

**My setting is the following:**

I have an action of $S_n$ on some $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $V$, by permuting a special basis:

$$<a^1_{1},\dots,a^1_{n!},a^2_{1},\dots,a^2_{n!},\dots,a^k_{n!},b_1,\dots,b_r> $$

where the orbit of $a^i_{1}$ is the set of all ${a^i_j}$ for $j=1,\dots,n!$ and $S_n$ acts on the rest of the basis by some unknown permutation of elements, but its orbit has not $n!$ elements.

There I have the subspace such that every element of $S_n$ acts by its sign, with the notation of my reference the subspace associated with $[1,\dots,1]$ (lets say the alternated space of $S_n$, also $V_{S_n}$). This can be written as

$$V_{S_n}=<\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{sign(\sigma)}\sigma(a^1_1),\dots,\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{sign(\sigma)}\sigma(a^k_1)> $$

Then I have the action of $S_{n-1}$ as a subgroup of $S_n$, formed by the elements that fix the first entry. My problem is that I know that $V_{S_n}$ will give me, a space that is alternated for $S_{n-1}$. This is because for each $j$ the set of $a^j_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n!$ contains $n$ orbits for the subgroup $S_{n-1}$, and I can perform a similar computation than the one to find $V_{S_n}$. But in general it is not the whole space such that $S_{n-1}$ acts by its sign, i.e. the alternated space for $S_{n-1}$ could have more elements from the $b_i$.

I have been told to look for representation theory (I am reading James Kerber, The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group) and I have concluded that I want to find the subspace associated to $[2,1,\dots,1]$, as defined in page 36 of that book, to find the rest of the alternated space that does not come from $V_{S_n}$.

**My question is the following:**

How do I find the subspace associated to $[2,1,\dots,1]$?

To find $[2,1,\dots,1]$ I need to induce some representations but the induced representation is an action over a different space, how can I find my subspace related to $[2,1,\dots,1]$ if I am changing the space to find $[2,1,\dots,1]$? Am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question has changed to include a particular representation, I'll add a separate answer.

The *regular representation* of $S_n$ is an $n!$-dimensional vector space with basis $\{v_\sigma:\sigma\in S_n\}$ a collection of linearly independent vectors with $\sigma\cdot v_{\tau}=v_{\sigma\tau}$ the group action, for $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$.  In the representation you give, the orbit condition means that it splits up into $k$ copies of the regular representation along with one copy of the unknown $\langle b_1,\dots, b_r\rangle$ representation.
$$ V = R\oplus R\oplus\dots\oplus R\oplus\langle b_1,\dots, b_r\rangle$$
That is, each $\langle a_1^j,\dots,a_{n!}^j\rangle$ is an invariant subspace isomorphic to $R$.  Let $B=\langle b_1,\dots, b_r\rangle$.

The representation $R$ is known to contain each irreducible representation of $S_n$ with multiplicity given by the dimension of that irreducible representation.  For example, the trivial and sign/alternating representations are each contained with multiplicity $1$ since they are both $1$-dimensional.

Restricting $V$ to $S_{n-1}$ involves seeing how each of the irreducible representations that exist in $R$ and $B$ split, using the branching rules.

If all we care about are the alternating representations, then $[2,1,\dots,1]$ and $[1,1,\dots,1]$ (partitions of $n$) are the only partitions that restrict to $[1,1,\dots,1]$ (partition of $n-1$).  The irreducible representation for $[2,1,\dots,1]$ is known to be $(n-1)$-dimensional, so $R$ contains a $(n-1)^2$-dimensional invariant subspace corresponding to this, which when restricted to $S_{n-1}$ contains a $(n-1)$-dimensional alternating invariant subspace.  So each $R$ contributes $1+(n-1)=n$ dimensions of alternating $S_{n-1}$ representations, $n-1$ dimensions of which did not come from the alternating $S_n$ representation.

Without knowing what $B$ is, there is not much to say.  It could have any number of $[1,1,\dots,1]$ and $[2,1,\dots,1]$ components already.

That said, we can use the character-based projection formulas.  The $S_n$ alternating part of $R$ is spanned by $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^\sigma v_\sigma$, and the $S_{n-1}$ alternating part is projected onto by
$$\pi_{\mathrm{alt}}(w) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}} (-1)^{\sigma} \sigma\cdot w$$
It is the same formula for $B$.

If you want to locate the alternating part that came from the $[2,1,\dots,1]$ part itself, you can use the projection formula for it then intersect the two subspaces.  To describe the character, let $\operatorname{tr}\sigma$ denote the number of fixed points for the permutation $\sigma$ (i.e., $\operatorname{tr}\sigma=\#\{i:\sigma(i)=i\}$).  The $[2,1,\dots,1]$ representation is the tensor product of the "reduced standard representation" with the alternating representation; I'll denote this by $-\mathrm{std}$.
$$\chi_{-\mathrm{std}}(\sigma) = (-1)^\sigma(\operatorname{tr}(\sigma)-1)$$

Then, for a representation $\phi$ of $S_n$, the projector is
$$\pi_{-\mathrm{std}}(w) = \frac{n-1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} (-1)^\sigma(\operatorname{tr}(\sigma)-1)\phi_\sigma(w)$$
(note that $(-1)^\sigma=(-1)^{\sigma^{-1}}$ and $\operatorname{tr}(\sigma)=\operatorname{tr}(\sigma^{-1})$).

The composition $\pi_{\mathrm{alt}}\circ\pi_{-\mathrm{std}}$ gives the $S_{n-1}$ alternating part that was not the $S_n$ alternating part.

Comment: Just to check: to find the invariant subspace associated to $[2,1,\dots,1]$ in $B$ I have to apply $\pi_{-std}$ to the vectors that generate $B$, and if I want to see If there is some alternated part for $S_{n-1}$ then $\pi_{alt}$, am I understanding this right? I guess that if $\pi_{-std}$ is non-zero then there is non-zero alternated part, otherwise I would just apply $\pi_{alt}$ to $B$ to find my alternated part of $S_{n-1}$

Comment: @RGC Yes, applying $\pi_{\mathrm{alt}}$ gives the alternated $S_{n-1}$ part, $\pi_{-\mathrm{std}}$ gives the $[2,1,\dots,1]$ $S_{n}$ part, and the composition gives the intersection: the alternated $S_{n-1}$ part that is located inside the $[2,1,\dots,1]$ $S_{n}$ part (so it is the $S_{n-1}$ alternated part from the non-alternated $S_n$ part).  It is possible for either of these images to be zero, depending on $B$, but, yes, if $\pi_{-\mathrm{std}}$ is nonzero then the composition is nonzero due to the branching rules.

Comment: Perfect, one last think: I see that the representation of $[2,1,\dots,1]$ should be the tensor product of the standard and the alternated representation because the character is the product of these two characters and then the representation is uniquely determined through it, but doing this thing of polytabloids, for example (1,2) applied to the polytabloid of

|1|2|
|3|
|4|

is the polytabloid of 

|2|1|
|3|
|4|,

the action on each term of the tensor product of spaces on one term is a permutation but the sign-term is not performed (?).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also one little correction (I think):  "So each $R$ contributes 3 dimensions of alternating $S_{n−1}$ representations, 2 dimensions of which did not come from the alternating $S_n$ representation". Each $R$ splits in $n$ opies of the regular representation for $S_{n-1}$, $R'$. Each one of them gives one alternating representation so each $R$ contributes with $n$ $S_{n-1}$-alternating representations. This is coherent with the branching rules because it is about what subrepresentations appears at one given representation, but here we are dealign with more spaces and combinations of generators.

Comment: @RGC I'm not sure I follow your question (and it might be better as a new top-level question).  Counting the number of irreducible subrepresentations in the tensor product of two representations is in general difficult; tensoring with the sign/alternated representation is a special easy case due to characters.

Comment: I will do so, thank you again.

Comment: @RGC You're right about that correction, I miscounted quite badly (thought the projection formulas are fine).  "$2$" stands for $n-1$, since I was thinking about $S_3$ the whole time!  So $S_n$ contains $n-1$ copies of $[2,1,\dots,1]$, each when restricted gives a single alternated representation.  Restricted the alternated gives an additional alternated representation, so there are $n$ dimensions of $S_{n-1}$ alternated representations in $R$.

Comment: When stating the character of the representation $[2,1,\dots,1]$ it is $tr(\sigma)$ instead of $(tr(\sigma)-1)$. Otherwise the dimension of the representation (by the hook length formula for example), $n$, and the tensor product of the two representations, $1(n-1)$ do not agree. Do you agree?

Comment: @RGC The dimension of the $S_n$ representation $[2,1,\dots,1]$ is $n-1$ by the hook length formula.  The notation I used might be confusing: $\operatorname{tr}\sigma$ is the trace of $\sigma$ acting on the (non-reduced) standard permutation representation $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

To give some notation: let's have $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V_{S_n}$ be a basis where $S_n$ acts by permutation: for all $\sigma\in S_n$ and $1\leq i\leq n$, then $\sigma$ acts on $v_i$ by $\sigma\cdot v_i= v_{\sigma(i)}$.  This is the "natural permutation representation."

This representation splits into two subrepresentations, the one corresponding to the partition $[n]$ and the one corresponding to the partition $[n-1,1]$.  These are conjugate to the partitions you give.  The $[n]$ partition corresponds to the trivial representation, and it is spanned by $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$.  The $[n-1,1]$ partition is spanned by an orthogonal complement of the trivial representation, a subspace characterized by vectors $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i v_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i=0$; the subspace is spanned by the set $$\{v_j-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nv_i:1\leq j\leq n\}.$$
While this is not a basis, removing any vector from this set gives an independent set.

If you modify the action of $S_n$ on $V_{S_n}$ so that, in addition, the vector is multiplied by the sign (so that $\sigma\cdot v_i = (-1)^\sigma v_{\sigma(i)}$, where $(-1)^\sigma$ is the sign of $\sigma$), then you do get the subrepresentations corresponding to the partitions you mentioned.  The representation still splits along the same subspaces given above.

The effect on a decomposition from restricting a representation to a subgroup (like $S_{n-1}\subset S_n$) is that the subrepresentions might no longer be irreducible, and they might split further.  The branching rules for the symmetric group are that you take a partition and find all the ways of subtracting $1$ so that the partition remains valid (in nonincreasing order).  The $[n]$ partition has only one way, so it gives $[n-1]$, the trivial representation of $S_{n-1}$.  This is spanned by the same vector as before.  The $[n-1,1]$ partition has two ways, giving $[n-2,1]$ and $[n-1,0]=[n-1]$, so the second subspace splits into two irreducible representations of $S_{n-1}$, with the second being an additional trivial subrepresentation.

By staring at the basis for a little while, I noticed that $v_1-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nv_i$ is left invariant by $S_{n-1}$.  This is the additional trivial subrepresentation.  Again, orthogonal to this must be the $[n-2,1]$ subrepresentation.  Here are spanning sets:
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \{\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\}\\
A_2 &= \{v_1-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\}\\
A_3 &= \{v_j-\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^n v_i:2\leq j\leq n\}
\end{align*}
where $A_1\cup A_2$ together spans the two-dimensional space for the trivial $S_{n-1}$ subrepresentation of $V_{S_n}$ and $A_3$ spans the $[n-2,1]$ subrepresentation.  Just like the case of repeated eigenvalues, that two-dimensional subspace should be taken as a two-dimensional eigenspace; it only splits into two subspaces somewhat canonically from the noncanonical choice of how $S_{n-1}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ (there are many ways!)

Again, if we do the modified representation where we multiply by the sign, to match the partitions you give in your question, these are still the correct spanning sets.

---

A general computational way to locate a subrepresentation for a representation of a finite group is to calculate characters and then use those calculate a projection matrix.  If $V$ is an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ and $\chi_V(g)=\operatorname{tr}(\rho_g)$ is the character function, where $\rho_g:V\to V$ the action of $g\in G$ on $V$, then for $W$ another representation of $G$ with $\psi_g$ the action of $g\in G$ on $W$ we have a projector $\pi_V:W\to W$ whose image is the $V$ part of $W$.  It can be given by
$$\pi_V(w) = \frac{\dim V}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \chi_V(g^{-1})\psi_g(w).$$

For example, the trivial representation $T$ of $S_{n-1}$ has the character function $\chi_T(g)=1$ for all $g\in S_{n-1}$.  The projector then is
$$\pi_T(v_i) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}}v_{\sigma(i)}.$$
Notice what this does to a vector is average components $2$ through $n$.  That is,
$$\pi_T(\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i) = c_1v_1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=2}^n c_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=2}^n v_i\right).$$
So, another basis for the $S_{n-1}$ trivial part of $V_{S_n}$ is
$$\{v_1,\sum_{i=2}^n v_i\}.$$

Comment: I have added information about the action of my group and the specific problem I have. On the other hand, I do not want to find the representation $[2,1,\dots,1]$ but its invariant subspace. Maybe I am understanding something wrong from your answer, this is not my field at all.

Comment: @RGC "Irreducible subrepresentation" means (for finite groups) "invariant subspace that is not a direct sum of two nontrivial invariant subspaces."  The spanning sets I give are the indecomposable invariant subspaces (for the representation I used as an example, in the absence of any particular representation in original question).  What I was getting at in my answer is that you (1) can use branching rules to predict what happens when you restrict the group and (2) locate the easy invariant subspaces (like trivial or sign) then the rest is complementary (with respect to some inner product).

Comment: @RGC The general idea is that the irreducible representations of $S_n$ are indexed by Young diagrams (partitions of $n$ in nonincreasing order).  For an arbitrary representation $V$ of $S_n$, the Young diagrams index types of "simultaneous eigenvectors" for all of $S_n$, but the "eigenvectors" span higher-dimensional invariant subspaces.  An actual simultaneous eigenvector corresponds to a 1d irreducible subrepresentation.  To get other invariant subspaces, you can use the projector formula I mentioned, but you need the characters of $S_n$.

Comment: @RGC The thing I was not doing was constructing Specht modules, which are concrete irreducible representations corresponding to each Young diagram.  The point of these is to show these irreducible representations exist and are pairwise non-isomorphic.  But, given a partition $\lambda$ and a Specht module $S_\lambda$, the space $\hom_{S_n}(S_\lambda,V)$, if you can calculate it, can be used to locate the $\lambda$ invariant subspace of $V$.